# ajax is working perfectly getting form data but I can't pass it to input value (adding to cart)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I created an html form without a submit button that takes data selection and pass it to ajax function in orderto process it through PHP to get some data from mysql database. So far, I got everything to work with only one problem.

The problem is that after getting the form working in which it is a drop down menu I'm trying to pass the value to input in order to add the product ID to cart so the user can buy the selected item. That was actually working before adding the ajax function. I did echo the the product ID in the input but nothing helped whenever I press the 'add to cart button'.

To summerize, when I echo Product ID by itself to see if i'm passing the right value. I can see that the printed value is correct. but when I pass it to the input value it just doesn't work. Here is the code:
my HTML form:

```
<form>
    <select name="category" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select length</option>
        <option value="6008">15</option>
        <option value="6018">25</option>
        <option value="6034">30</option>
        <option value="6038">40</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

My ajax code:

```
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "forms.php?", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("q=" + str);

    }
</script>
```

after getting value and pass it to database I displayed data using this:

```
<div id="txtHint">  </div>
```

and here is the input used to add product id to cart: ( so I just need to echo Prod id in order to process the add to cart button).

```
<input type="hidden" name="thermospace_cart_1_ID_Add" value="<?php echo ['Productid']  ?>" />
```

Comment: Do you know what the product_id is when you load the page or would you only get it after you've run your ajax method?

Comment: It's actually after running ajax.  This is the process:  the product id is the value number  that user clicks on form so it is basically a string that passed to ajax. then it goes to php file to get processed in the database by comparing the value with the actual Product id in the database to get the correct row from database.@RossWilson

Comment: that way used to be working perfectly with a submit input button in the form to send data. but I added ajax because I didn't want the page to reload when selecting a value from the drop down menu. So the only way was using Ajax to process the data. and I'm wondering because it's working perfectly it just doesn't when I echo selected value into cart. @RossWilson

Comment: It sounds like you need to return the product id in the response to the ajax request and then use javascript to set the value on the input.

Comment: any idea on how to do that ? I tried setting up the input button to an id and then used get element by id and assigned it to the response but still no luck @RossWilson

Comment: I would suggest looking at something like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qJT09LAh64 . It's a few years old but it should help you with the core concepts.